# Can't load image in modal using Partial View by transporting data by Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to use Partial View to load modal with image from wwwroot folder.
It works with explicitly setting imgage source to directory of image. It doesn't work with using a model with property that holds path to image.

I checked string that is created and save to model. To me it looks good.

Model that is send to Partial View:

```
public class ImagePath
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
```

Partial View:

```
//that image is displayed
<img class="img-fluid" src="~/images/Equipment/8711-rys.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" />

//that image isn't displayed
<img class="img-fluid" src="@Model.Path" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

Get function that calls and returns Partial View:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetModalImage(string path)
        {
            var pathToImage = "~/images/Equipment" + path;
            ImagePath = new ImagePath
            {
                Path = pathToImage
            };
            return Partial("_ModalImage", ImagePath);
        }
```

View code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
            $('#myInput').on('click', function () {
                $('.modal-body').load(`/treeview/modalimage?path=${'/8711-rys.jpg'}`);
            });
        })
</script>

<div id="imgModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Nazwa narzedzia</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't work with using a model with property that holds path to image.

If you checked the rendered html source of `<img>` tag(s) in browser side, you would find it look like below.

[image]

To make the second `<img>` tag render well, you can use `@Url.Content(Model.Path)` to convert a virtual (relative, starting with ~/) path to an application absolute path.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="@Url.Content(Model.Path)" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

Another approach is setting `pathToImage` to `"/images/Equipment" + path`, like below.

```
var pathToImage = "/images/Equipment" + path;
ImagePath = new ImagePath
{
    Path = pathToImage
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful. Now I understand what I did wrong.